Ubuntu installation is stuck at "Get 24" in Windows 10 / VirtualBox
I am trying to install Ubuntu 24.04.01 on my VirtualBox. I keep getting stuck at the "get 24" step. I disabled my Hyper-V in Windows settings and enabled virtualization in my BIOS prior to installing. Please see the screenshot I attached.


I tried the newest virtualbox too. Virtalbox 7.1 has troubles with Ubuntu 24.04, not sure why yet. It hung for me. Using virtualbox 7.0.20 worked to get it to boot though I quickly encountered other usability problems. What version of Virtualbox are you using?
